# PySpark "column" object content to display

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, displayobject

I am just starting to learn PySpark. I have created a column object, and now I want to see what is in it. Unfortunately, all my research efforts concluded with proposals to access a column of a Spark dataframe. But I want to know how to see what data is in the column object, that I already have.
There must be a simple way, but no success to find it.

The code that created the column object:

```
baskets=groups.agg(pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list("product_id"))['collect_list(product_id)']
```

I expect something like the `baskets.show()`, but that just tells me

> column object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

This creates a dataframe:

```py
import pyspark
baskets=groups.agg(pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list("product_id"))
```

(However, normally we use less verbose lines)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
baskets = groups.agg(F.collect_list("product_id"))
```

Now, `baskets` is a dataframe and you can use `baskets.show()`

In your code, you have also appended `['collect_list(product_id)']`. This way you created a reference in your code to the column. However, Spark has not created this column. So, there's nothing to display. It's just a reference in the code, so that code can become more readable. [Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.html) are the methods of pyspark.sql.Column class. There's nothing there to display column's values. It will "get" values only when it is displayed as part of a dataframe.

It takes some time to understand how Spark works. It uses *lazy evaluation*.

> lazy evaluation means that if you tell Spark to operate on a set of data, it listens to what you ask it to do, writes down some shorthand for it so it doesn’t forget, and then does absolutely nothing. It will continue to do nothing, until you ask it for the final answer.

<sup>https://developer.hpe.com/blog/the-5-minute-guide-to-understanding-the-significance-of-apache-spark/</sup>

Comment: Thanks for reinforcing. I was afraid I miss something very basic, just becaose I can not find it.
May I ask a good practice to display a column; it often is necessary when we have hundreds of features.

Comment: `df.select('column_name').show()` ?

Comment: As I have told you, you cannot just display a `Column` class object. You can display dataframes easily, so do just that.